# Can't figure out query logic

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Help me figure out how to structure this meta_query within my post query!

There are two taxonomies attached to my post type ('audition_type', and 'union_requirement'). On a page of my site the user is able to use checkboxes to filter a query of the post type ('audition'). The below meta_query is working fine to get all posts that are in the terms that the user selects but it's not quite right. 
I need it to return all the posts that match ANY of the terms selected in the 'audition_type' taxonomy and then narrow it down further by only getting posts that have the selected 'union_requirement' terms selected . 
So, almost like a query within a query. That's where I can't quite figure out the logic.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
    'key' => 'audition_type',
    'value' => $typeIDs,
    ),
    array(
    'key' => 'union_requirement',
    'value' => $unionIDs
    )
),
```

`$typeIDs` and `$unionIDs` variables are arrays containing the term IDs if that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay on this everyone, I was out of town! 
Here is what I figured out and am using today. I had to check for the cases where one taxonomy was selected and one was not, which actually only requires a simple tax query, but that was giving me null values and breaking the query, so I had to use some conditionals instead to build it.

$typeIDs and $unionsIDs are arrays of taxonomies that are selected.

Thanks for your suggestions!

```
//Set the proper tax_query based on what we're looking for
if ($typeIDs && $unionIDs) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'audition_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $typeIDs,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'union_requirement',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $unionIDs,
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    );
} elseif ($typeIDs) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'audition_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $typeIDs,
        )
    );
} else if ($unionIDs) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'union_requirement',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $unionIDs,
        )
    );
} else {
    $args['tax_query'] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your description right you want posts which have *any* `$typeIDs`, but *all* of `$unionIDs` ?

Aside from wrong `meta_query` choice, you miss `operator` argument which specifies which kind of match you want.

I think your query should be something like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND', // you want both conditions to match
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'audition_type',
    'terms' => $typeIDs,
    'operator' => 'IN', // this is default, just showing you difference
    ),
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'union_requirement',
    'terms' => $unionIDs,
    'operator' => 'AND', // not default, we want matches to all terms
    )
),
```

See [Taxonomy Parameters in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) for further documentation.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code, meta query will not give you the results you want. Please go through the meta query for more details.
[Meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)
Or go [here](https://cheekymonkeymedia.ca/blog/using-wordpress-to-query-multiple-taxonomies) for reference.

```
<?php 
$myquery = array(
                'numberposts'=>-1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'audition_type',
                                'terms' => $typeIDs
                            ),
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'union_requirement',
                                'terms' => $unionIDs
                            ),
                ),
            );
query_posts($myquery);
```

?>

Comment: Downvoted because of 1.) The use of `query_posts`. **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. 2.) Please explain what your code does and how it works, this is just a useless code dump